# Chart.js: Combined Line and Bar Data

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I want to create a Chart with [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) containing two different datasets: One Line Data Set and one Bar Data Set.

You can see my whole code for that here:

```
/**
 * 
 */
function initCombinedChart() {
    /**
     *
     */
    $("canvas").each(function() {
        var config = getConfigCombined($(this).attr("id"));
        var context = $(this);
        var combined = new Chart(context, config);
    });
}

/**
 * 
 * @param id
 * @returns {___anonymous464_473}
 */
function getConfigCombined(id) {
    var currentId = id;
    var currentIdNumber = currentId.substring((currentId.lastIndexOf("_") + 1), currentId.length);
    var entry = $("#" + id).data("entry");

    var labelMeasure = $("#evaluations_combined_measures").data("txt");
    var labelInsulin = $("#evaluations_combined_insulins").data("txt");

    var datasetLine = dataCombinedLine(labelMeasure, entry);
    var datasetCombined = dataCombinedBar(labelInsulin, entry);

    var config = {
        type: "bar",
        data: {
            labels: labelsFromEntry(entry),
            datasets: []
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            title: {
                display: false
            },
            legend: {
                position: "bottom"
            },
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    position: "bottom",
                    type: "time",
                    time: {
                        unit: "hour",
                        format: "HH:mm",
                        tooltipFormat: "HH:mm",
                        displayFormats: {
                            hour: "HH:mm",
                            day: "HH:mm",
                            week: "HH:mm",
                            month: "HH:mm",
                            quarter: "HH:mm",
                            year: "HH:mm"
                        }
                    },
                    gridLines : {
                        display : false
                    }
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    type: "linear",
                    display: true,
                    position: "left",
                    id: "y-axis-0",
                    gridLines: {
                        show: true,
                    }
                }, {
                    type: "linear",
                    display: true,
                    position: "right",
                    id: "y-axis-1",
                    gridLines: {
                        show: false
                    }
                }]
            },
        }
    }

    if (datasetLine != null) {
        config.data.datasets.push(datasetLine);
    }

    if (datasetCombined != null) {
        config.data.datasets.push(datasetCombined);
    }

    return config;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param entry
 * @returns {Array}
 */
function labelsFromEntry(entry) {
    var result = [];
    var entryCombined;
    var entryMeasure;
    var entryInsulin;

    if (entry.indexOf("-") >= 0) {
        entryCombined = entry.split("-");
        entryMeasure = entryCombined[0];
        entryInsulin = entryCombined[1];
    } else {
        entryMeasure = entry;
        entryInsulin = "";
    }

    var entryMeasureArray = entryMeasure.split(";");
    var entryInsulinArray = entryInsulin.split(";");

    entryMeasureArray.forEach(function(entry) {
        var entryPair = entry.split(",");
        var date = parseFloat(entryPair[0]);
        var dateFormat = moment(date).format("HH:mm");

        if (!result.includes(dateFormat)) {
            result.push(dateFormat);
        }
    });

    entryInsulinArray.forEach(function(entry) {
        var entryPair = entry.split(",");
        var date = parseFloat(entryPair[0]);
        var dateFormat = moment(date).format("HH:mm");

        if (!result.includes(dateFormat)) {
            result.push(dateFormat);
        }
    });

    return result;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param label
 * @param entry
 * @returns {___anonymous3118_3127}
 */
function dataCombinedLine(label, entry) {
    var dataset = {
        type: "line",
        label: label,   
        lineTension: 0,
        backgroundColor: "#4078A7",
        borderCapStyle: "butt",
        borderJoinStyle: "miter",
        borderColor: "#4078A7",
        pointRadius: 5,
        pointBorderColor: "#4078A7",
        pointBackgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
        pointBorderWidth: 3,
        pointHoverRadius: 5,
        pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
        pointHoverBorderWidth: 3,
        pointHitRadius: 5,
        data: dataCombinedLineFromEntries(entry),
        yAxisID : "y-axis-0",
        fill: false
    }

    return dataset;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param label
 * @param entry
 * @returns {___anonymous3299_3308}
 */
function dataCombinedBar(label, entry) {
    var dataset = {
        type: "bar",
        label: label,
        backgroundColor: "#239471",
        borderCapStyle: "butt",
        borderJoinStyle: "miter",
        borderColor: "#239471",
        data: dataCombinedBarFromEntries(entry),
        yAxisID : "y-axis-1"
    }

    return dataset;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param entry
 * @returns {Array}
 */
function dataCombinedLineFromEntries(entry) {
    var result = [];
    var entryMeasures = entry.split("-")[0];
    var entryMeasuresArray = entryMeasures.split(";");

    entryMeasuresArray.forEach(function(entry) {
        var entryPair = entry.split(",");
        var date = parseFloat(entryPair[0]);
        var value = entryPair[1];

        var data = {
            x: moment(date).format("HH:mm"),
            y: entryPair[1]
        }

        result.push(data);
    });

    return result;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param entry
 * @returns {Array}
 */
function dataCombinedBarFromEntries(entry) {
    var result = [];

    if (entry.indexOf("-") >= 0) {
        var entryInsulins = entry.split("-")[1];
        var entryInsulinsArray = entryInsulins.split(";");

        entryInsulinsArray.forEach(function(entry) {
            var entryPair = entry.split(",");
            var date = parseFloat(entryPair[0]);
            var value = entryPair[1];

            var data = {
                x: moment(date).format("HH:mm"),
                y: entryPair[1]
            }

            result.push(entryPair[1]);
        });
    }

    return result;
}
```

With this code i managed to put both datasets into one chart, but there are two problems left. The first problem is that the first and the last bar are overlapping with the yAxis:

[image]

**How can I disable the overlap?**

The second problem remaining is the following: The line data and the bar data arent always matching. That means: If i have a line data entry for 08:00 o'clock that does not mean that there is a bar data entry for 08:00 o'clock. Same counts the other way: if there is a bar data for 12:00 o'clock it does not mean that there is a line data matching for 12:00 o'clock. There can be X data entries for the line data but Y data entries for the bar data. For that i created x and y values for the line data:

```
    entryMeasuresArray.forEach(function(entry) {
        var entryPair = entry.split(",");
        var date = parseFloat(entryPair[0]);
        var value = entryPair[1];

        var data = {
            x: moment(date).format("HH:mm"),
            y: entryPair[1]
        }

        result.push(data);
    });
```

This is working perfectly for the line data. But unfortunately i could not find such an option for the bar data. The bar data does not accept x and y values, it only accepts the y value:

```
        entryInsulinsArray.forEach(function(entry) {
            var entryPair = entry.split(",");
            var date = parseFloat(entryPair[0]);
            var value = entryPair[1];

            var data = {
                x: moment(date).format("HH:mm"),
                y: entryPair[1]
            }

            result.push(entryPair[1]);
        });
```

**So how can i define x and y values for the bar data as i can define them for the line data?**

**EIDT**

Im using the latest version 2.1.6

**EDIT 2**

Here a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/av15kuwj/6/) to demonstrate the problems

Comment: from your fiddle first bar is not getting displayed

Comment: Debugging help questions require a [mcve] as per the [help]. Your code is not minimal. Please [edit] your question to make sure that your code is Minimal (only the code necessary to reproduce your issue in your question), Complete (users do not need anything else to reproduce your issue), and Verifiable (the provided code does reproduce the exact issue you are facing). As it is your question is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Note that this is also a common [downvote reason](http://idownvotedyoubecause.com/so/TooMuchCode).

Comment: If you dont see that all requirements are posted correctly than you did not understand the problem. Also i already got a good answer. So others did understand it well. If you dont see the need of answering you dont need to answer at all. Also others did upvote my question. So there was a need of knowledge to that question. Dont know why you are bulling around with that simple approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first problem :

**How can I disable the overlap?**

```
xAxes: [{
  position: "bottom",
  //type: "time",    // erase this line
  time: {
    unit: "hour",
    format: "HH:mm",
    tooltipFormat: "HH:mm",
    displayFormats: {
      hour: "HH:mm",
      day: "HH:mm",
      week: "HH:mm",
      month: "HH:mm",
      quarter: "HH:mm",
      year: "HH:mm"
    }
  }
}],
```

In the XAxes erase the line *type: "time"*, this option imply that the graph has to start in zero without margin.

**The second problem:**

I think the best way to represent your data:

```
var data = [
  { x: "08:00", y_line: "110", y_bar: "30"}, 
  { x: "09:00", y_line: "120", y_bar: "35"}, 
  { x: "10:00", y_line: "130", y_bar: null},
  { x: "11:00", y_line: "140", y_bar: 45}
];
```

With this representation you force that each "time" has two measurements, one for the bar and one for the line that can have  a numerical value or a *null* value.

Then with some functions you can get the sets:

```
function getLine(){
    var arr = [];
    data.forEach(function(entry) { 
       var data = { x: entry.x, y: entry.y_line}
       arr.push(data);
    });
    return arr;
}

function getBar(){
    var arr = [];
    data.forEach(function(entry) { 
       arr.push(entry.y_bar);
    });
    return arr;
}

function getLabels(){
    var arr = [];
    data.forEach(function(entry) { 
       arr.push(entry.x);
    });
    return arr;
}
```

Then you introduce the values in your configuration like this:

```
{
 type: "bar",
 label: labelInsulin,
 backgroundColor: "#239471",
 borderCapStyle: "butt",
 borderJoinStyle: "miter",
 borderColor: "#239471",
 data: getBar(),           // like this
 yAxisID : "y-axis-1"
}
```

If a "bar" has value *null* it doesn't appear. And because the "bar" has the same number of elements than the "line" they always match.

Comment: I have no idea why someone downvoted this answer. It worked perfectly.