# How can I make two of my lines in Chart JS thicker

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have made a chart with Chart JS, as you can see in my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aervw3p6/). There are three lines in this chart. I want to have the orange and yellow line to be thicker than it is right now. The green dotted line is good as it is.

I've searched around, and tried some things. But I haven't found the right solution yet. I hope that my question is clear, and that someone can help me with this.

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.6/Chart.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<canvas id="canvas2"></canvas>
```

**JavaScript**

```
Chart.defaults.global.legend.display = false;
var lineChartData = {
labels: ['20°', '30°', '40°', '50°', '60°', '70°', '80°'],
datasets: [{
  data: [null, null, null, 400, 320, 220, 90],
  pointBorderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
  pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
  borderColor: '#FFEC8B',
  pointBorderWidth: 0,
  pointHoverRadius: 0,
  pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
  pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
  pointHoverBorderWidth: 0,
  lineWidth: 100,
  pointRadius: 0,
  pointHitRadius: 0,
},{
  data: [550, 520, 470, 400, null, null, null],
  borderColor: '#ff8800',
  pointBorderWidth: 0,
  pointHoverRadius: 0,
  pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
  pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
  pointHoverBorderWidth: 0,
  pointRadius: 0,
  pointHitRadius: 0,
},
{
    data: [220, 220, 220, 220, 220, 220, 220],
    borderColor: '#008080',
    borderDash: [10, 10],
    pointBorderWidth: 0,
    pointHoverRadius: 0,
    pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
    pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    pointHoverBorderWidth: 0,
    pointRadius: 0,
    pointHitRadius: 0,
  }
]
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas2").getContext("2d");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
 type: "line",
 beginAtZero: true,
 scaleOverride:true,
 scaleSteps:9,
 scaleStartValue:0,
 lineWidth: 100,
 scaleStepWidth:100,
 data: lineChartData,
 options: {
    elements: {
        line: {
            fill: false
        }
    },
    style: {
      strokewidth: 10
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        display: true,
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Temperatuur - Celcius'
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        display: true,
        ticks: {
            max: 600,
            min: 0,
            stepSize: 200,
            userCallback: function(value, index, values) {
                value = value.toString();
                value = value.split(/(?=(?:...)*$)/);
                value = value.join('.');
                return value + '%';
              }
        },
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Rendement'
        }
      }]
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You were close to it !
Actually, the attribute you have to edit is not `lineWidth` but `borderWidth` (in the [first example](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#getting-started-creating-a-chart) of Chart.js docs, you can see the attribute).

---

As stated in [the example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/lineTo#Examples) of the MDN doc of [`lineTo`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/lineTo) :

> Use the beginPath() to begin a path to draw a line on, move the pen with moveTo() and use the stroke() method to actually draw the line.

The line is basically a rectangle with a width of `0`. Then the width of the line is calculated using the rectangle border width.

---

So you simply have to edit your dataset this way :

```
datasets: [{
    // ...
    borderWidth: 1 // and not lineWidth
    // ...
}]
```

I also have [updated your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aervw3p6/1/) with the edit, and you can see that it is working now.

Comment: Oh man, thank you so much! Why do call it borderWidth, in my opinion it makes no sense?

Comment: @StijnWesterhof As I explained, lines in canvas (then also in Chart.js) are drawn as a rectangle with a width of 0. So the line width is linked to the "*rectangle*" border width. Then, by editing the border width, you also edit the line width. Chart.js devs could have edited this to have more sense .. Anyway, glad I helped ! :)

Comment: The corners of the lines that I've increased are overlapping the chart now. It is not really a big problem, but do you know how to fix this, that it will go behind the chart borders?

Comment: @StijnWesterhof You now have the same problem as in [this other question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38144776/chart-js-combined-line-and-bar-data). Unfortunately, I have no idea about what could fix the issue ..

Answer (score 2):

if this helps, or you still discern this method as presentable you can set the borderwidth relatively high like 50.

```
datasets:[{
    borderWidth: 50
}]
 //at your options put this
 options: {
            legend: {
                display: true,
                labels: {
                    fontSize: 16, //point style's size is based on font style not boxed width.
                    usePointStyle:true,
                }
            }
```

you check `usePointStyle` at the docs https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html#legend-label-configuration