# How can I make line on chart thinner?

Tags: chart.js, chart.js2

Is there any properties to make line in line chart thicker or thinner excluding "borderWidth"? I need to make line chart with lines thinner than default  and don't know how do so

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`borderWidth` is the only property you can use to make it thinner or thicker, because a line literally has no thickness of its own. You can see the explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38396605/4887159), along with the fiddle.

Also have a look at the [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html), there aren't a lot of options anyway to work with for line chart.

Comment: I saw that question before, but it only solves the problem how to make the line thicker. Anyway, thank you, I think I should ask this question to developers